# How to record Skype calls (audio) on Debian 6?

Tags: debian, skype, recording

I conduct business over Skype. Sometimes when I talk to clients they give a lot of instructions real quick. It would be nice to have a way to record conversations so that I could listen to them at a later point of time when I need them.

I have noticed people suggesting 'recordmydesktop', 'xvidcap', and 'ffmpeg' for recording. However, I DO NOT want to record video. I just want to record voice calls **while having my headphones on**. This means that I should be able to record the sound **inline**, not record it externally by pulling out my headphones and putting my clients on speaker (I know they can hear that, and they don't like it).

If there are ways you know that can solve my problem on a Debian 6 system, please let me know.

Comment: Are you using pulseaudio? `ps xa | grep pulseaudio` should show one if you are.

Comment: Yes I am. "ps xa | grep pulseaudio
 3304 ?        S<l    1:49 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
18810 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep pulseaudio"

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502380/streaming-pulseaudio-to-file-possibly-with-gstreamer ... I wish we could move that question over here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Via ALSA emulation

I don't have a Debian 6.0.x box to test on, but I think this way will probably work. Courtesy an [example on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#ALSA_monitor_source).

First, use `pacmd list-sources` to find the name of your sound card's monitor stream. Grep for `.monitor` works pretty well:

```
$ pacmd list-sources | grep '\.monitor'
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
        name: <alsa_output.usb-stereo-link_stereo-link_1200_USB_DAC-00-DAC.analog-stereo.monitor>
```

I have two cards, hence two monitors. Then edit your `~/.asoundrc` to set up an ALSA device for it, by adding lines like (but of course use your monitor device name, not mine):

```
pcm.pulse_monitor {
    type pulse
    device alsa_output.usb-stereo-link_stereo-link_1200_USB_DAC-00-DAC.analog-stereo.monitor
}

ctl.pulse_monitor {
    type pulse
    device alsa_output.usb-stereo-link_stereo-link_1200_USB_DAC-00-DAC.analog-stereo.monitor
}
```

Then use `arecord -f s16_le -t wav -r 44100 -D pulse_monitor /tmp/outfile.wav` to record.

### Older PulseAudio Utilities

Instead of using ALSA emulation, you can use `parecord` on the monitor you found above. Do so like this: `parecord -d alsa_output.usb-stereo-link_stereo-link_1200_USB_DAC-00-DAC.analog-stereo.monitor outfile.wav`. That should work with `parec` as well (in the LAME example below)

### Newer PulseAudio Utilities

PulseAudio ships with a `parecord` command-line utility that can record sound going through it.

To use it, first find the index of the stream you want to capture. Easy way from the command line is `pacmd list-sink-inputs`, which should give something like this:

```
1 sink input(s) available.
    index: 10720
        driver: <protocol-native.c>
        ⋮
        client: 87 <Chromium>
        ⋮
```

I've omitted a bunch of lines; but you can see that's Chromium (where I have a music player running). The `index: 10720` bit is important.

To record it, it's as simple as `parecord --monitor-stream 10720 outfile.wav`. You can also write the output to stdout and use it as part of a pipe with `parec`; for example if you're short on disk space you could directly encode to MP3:

```
parec --monitor-stream 10720 --format s16le --channels 2 --rate 44100 \
    | lame -r -s 44.1 -b 16 --signed --little-endian --preset medium /dev/stdin outfile.mp3
```

Comment: It says "parecord: unrecognized option '--monitor-stream". I checked out the 'man' of parecord, the '--monitor-stream' switch isn't listed there. Any ideas?

Comment: @intellikid Hmmm, must not be present in PulseAudio 0.9. That's what I get for testing on jessie... Trying to find an alternative.

Comment: "pulseaudio --version" tells me I am using version 2.0

Comment: @intellikid OK! have another method that'll hopefully work. Also, you sure you're on Debian 6.0 (squeeze) and not 7.0 (wheezy)?

Comment: @intellikid also, if you have parecord, it can probably be used on that monitor stream directly... Without the `--monitor` option.

Comment: @intellikid OK, that third option is in the answer now. Please let me know if any of these work... I don't have a system with 6.0.x (or even 7.x) to test on...

Comment: It worked!! The first solution (by editing the ~/.asoundrc). Thank You! I do have a question though. I wanted to record **both** sides of the conversation. Mine as well. Since this records the sound **inline**, would it capture what I say (my laptop mic) as well?

Comment: @intellikid It'll only record what's being sent to the speakers. You could do a separate record to grab the mic as well, then mix them together using e.g., audacity. I'd try the second option, I suspect it'll work too, and is less setup work (no files to edit). It's also really easy to use the device name of your mic there to grab that.